# How to set default identity login page in .net core 6 mvc instead of index page in program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I am developing web app with .net core 6. How can I set default page to Identity Login page instead of index page in program.cs. Below is my program.cs code

````
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ASPNETCOREPRJ.Areas.Identity.Data;
using ASPNETCOREPRJ.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBContextConnection");builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)

    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages(); 

app.Run();```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code to:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
});
```