# Asp.net Identity keeps redirecting back to login page after successfull login

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0, c#-10.0

I have created a .NET 6 mvc project from scratch and selected "Individual account" option for authentication during the project creation. Later, I added identity scaffold and then I created a new _AuthLayout.cshtml for Identity functionality.(as shown in below image).

[image]

I am setting login page as default landing page in Program.cs file. Now I want to redirect the user to home controller index page after successful login but the website keeps redirecting back to login page after successful login.
I have seen and tried many similar questions on stack overflow but my problem is not solved.

Here are my code:

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication2.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

**Login.cshtml.cs**

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

   
    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }
   
    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }
   
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
   
    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    
    public class InputModel
    {           
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

       
        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

**_AuthLayout.cshtml**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/DemoApp.styles.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>   
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    @RenderBody()
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

**_ViewStart.cshtml** (this view start is under area folder)

```
@{
Layout = "_AuthLayout";
}
```

And here are the links that I have referred:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421996/net-core-5-razor-pages-cookie-authentication-redirects-to-the-login-page-after)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602203/asp-net-core-identity-successful-login-redirecting-back-to-login-page)

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong? thank you

Comment: What's your _AuthLayout.cshtml ? Could you share it ? And do you use it in your Index view ?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the _AuthLayout.cshtml file. I am not using _AuthLayout in index view. My requirement is when the application will load, user will be landed on Login page and after successful login , the application should redirect to Home Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove below code:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
});
```

> options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login",
> "");

Set the default page to /Account/Login, that's why Asp.net Identity keeps redirecting back to login page after successfull login.

result:
[image]

You can read [AddAreaPageRoute Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pageconventioncollectionextensions.addareapageroute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.

Comment: But one question , how does the code knows to load login page as default ? I referred this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323378/how-to-set-default-identity-login-page-in-net-core-6-mvc-instead-of-index-page earlier to set login page as default landing page.

Comment: @ShakshamSingh What do you mean  load login page as default ? You mean before successful login load login page or  after   successful login load login page?

Comment: When the website will load , I want to show login page to the user like we do in many websites. The user will enter his credentials and then he will be redirected to Home page or dashboard page.

Comment: @ShakshamSingh  Because we  place the`[Authorize]` attribute on the controller ,`[Authorize] ` attribute force users to identify themselves to get into this controller . Identity will load login page first   . You can read[Introduction to authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  and [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#prevent-publish-of-static-identity-assets)to know more.

Comment: @ShakshamSingh      The  ASP.NET Core Identity will redirect an unauthorized user to the /Account/Login , these code is built-in .